# Create image from included PHP file

Tags: php, image

I would like to create an image from an included PHP file, there is an error of undefined variable:

index.php

```
<?php
// get servers and domains
$serSel = 'SELECT * FROM servers';
$serReq = $connexion->query($serSel);
$serRes = $serReq->fetchAll();
$totalSer = count($serRes);

foreach($serRes as $Serv)
{

$s_global_size  = $Serv['s_global_size'];
$s_used_size    = $Serv['s_used_size'];
$s_creation     = $Serv['s_creation'];
$s_expiry       = $Serv['s_expiry'];

$diskSpace = ($e_name == 'domain')  ?   '-'  : format_bytes($s_global_size);

echo $diskSpace;

$diskUsage = ($e_name == 'domain')  ?   '-'  : format_bytes($s_used_size);

echo $diskUsage;

$s_left_size = ($s_global_size - $s_used_size);
$sLeftSize = ($e_name == 'domain')  ?   '-'  : format_bytes($s_left_size);
echo $sLeftSize;

}


echo '<img src="Idara/Statistics/webdata_circle.php">';
```

?>

webdata_circle.php

```
<?php
// create image
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(180, 180);

$usagePerc = ($diskUsage * 360)/$diskSpace;

// allocate some colors
$red = imagecolorallocate($image, 192, 0, 0);
$red1 = imagecolorallocate($image, 192, 20, 0);
$green = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 133 ,62);
$green1 = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 140 ,62);
$trans = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0); // transparent background

// Make the background transparent
imagecolortransparent($image, $trans);


imagefilledarc($image, 80, 80, 150, 150, 0, 360, $red, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagefilledarc($image, 80, 80, 150, 150, 0, $usagePerc, $green, IMG_ARC_PIE);

// flush image
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

The error returned is:

```
 PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: diskUsage in webdata_circle.php on line 8
 PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: diskSpace in webdata_circle.php on line 8
 PHP Warning:  Division by zero in webdata_circle.php on line 8
```

Thanks in advance

NB: This is the full code, I hope it will help

Comment: what is unclear in notices/warning you are facing?

Comment: We are missing some information here. Where do $diskUsage and $diskSpace get set?

Comment: Read the error message. If it's complaining of undefined variables, you might want to define those variables.

Comment: Where are you declaring `$diskUsage` and `$diskSpace`?

Comment: diskUsage and diskSpace are coming from a query set before printing the image

Comment: Post more code then.

Comment: I added some more codes

Comment: Are you not including "webdata_circle.php" in your first piece of code? How do both bodies of code tie in together? Put your entire codes together, should work.

Comment: If I include it, it contains this error: the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Comment: I used index.php as first page, and include webdata_circle into the image code

Comment: The problem is that when `webdata_circle.php` is called by the browser, it is a completely separate web request. Thus the variables you have defined in `webdata_circle.php` are not seen.

Comment: That's because your header is below `echo '<img src="Idara/Statistics/webdata_circle.php">';` - You need to have your header above any output. Try placing the img below `imagedestroy($image);`

Comment: I added the webdata_circle in index.php, it displays the same error, see how I did it: `require_once 'Idara/Statistics/webdata_circle.php';` and then some codes, then I printed the image: `echo '<img src="Idara/Statistics/webdata_circle.php">';`

Comment: If there is any type of output before your header, a space, HTML, etc. that will contribute to the error. Keep that in mind and rework your codes. Take `echo '<img src="Idara/Statistics/webdata_circle.php">';` out of index.php and place it below the header in the other file. index.php should not contain any output also, including HTML etc. cookies, css etc.

Comment: All my variables are in index.php, so if I call webdata_circle from the image `echo '<img src="Idara/Statistics/webdata_circle.php">';` it will not define all variables from index and put them in webdata_circle??

Comment: Try it it out and see. That's how I do it and was faced with the same problem as you before. Variables don't count as output before header. If you have any errors in your query, then that will count as output, because SQL is spitting out an error that it won't let you see because of the header. The logic behind it is; query/generate img/header/show image.

Comment: In your index.php file: All the echos `echo $diskSpace;` etc. count as output. Either comment those out or remove them. Remember, no output before header; none at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following lines to `webdata_circle.php`, on the 2nd line:

```
$diskPath = dirname(__FILE__); 
$diskUsage  = disk_total_space ($diskPath); 
$diskUsage  = disk_free_space ($diskPath);
```

Comment: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant __PATH__ - assumed '__PATH__' in

Comment: `__PATH__` not __PATH__

Comment: yes, I did it, it is converted because of this website bbcode

Comment: Try `__FILE__` instead of `__PATH__`. I corrected now.

Comment: I added some corrections, and it works, however, the problem is to define once my variables